# SQL inner join and subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a sub query on an inner join to get back all department numbers and names from a table that do not have programmer in the department, but I am having a little trouble as it returns no values. Here is my code, thanks for any help.

```
select Departments.Department_Name, Departments.Department_No
from employees inner join departments 
on departments.department_No = employees.Department_No 
where Employees.Department_No != 
            (select Department_Name
             from Employees, Departments
             where Job_ID = '%pro%')
```

Comment: You are comparing `department_name` to `department_no`.  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Could you provide a table / result example?

Comment: Your subquery is using `Employees, Departments` with no join - this doesn't seem right either.  You should edit your question with your table structures, sample data and the desired result.

Comment: That JobID comparison might be intended to use the LIKE operator rather than the equals sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, you want something like this:

```
select d.Department_Name, d.Department_No
from departments d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employees
                  WHERE d.Department_No = Department_No
                  AND Job_ID LIKE '%pro%')
```

This selects all departments, for which there doesn't exist an employee whose job_ib contains 'pro'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select d1.Department_Name,d1.Department_No 
from departments d1 
where d1.Department_No in ( select e1.Department_No 
                            from Employees e1  
                            where e1.Department_No=d1.Department_No and
                            e1.job_id not in ('programmer'));
```